# How to use Unicode for a ForeignKeyField, Django

Tags: python, django, unicode, models

I have a ForeignKeyField in model number one that displays a __unicode__self.name.

I want to use the same unicode in the second model, but everytime I try to do that it's says I need to encode it, I've been trying to solve this by reading Django docs but I can't figure out how.

Here's the code:

```
class Viaje(models.Model):
    cliente = models.ForeignKey(Cliente)
    fecha = models.CharField(max_length=244, blank=True)
    origen = models.CharField(max_length=244, blank=True)
    destino = models.CharField(max_length=244, blank=True)
    tracto_numero = models.CharField(max_length=244, blank=True)



    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.cliente
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return unicode(self.cliente)
```

Comment: Wow!! This works as I wanted, thank you very much! :)

Comment: Don't call double-underscore methods directly. Instead use `unicode(self.cliente)`.